# Set focus on the selected item when tabbing in a WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, listbox

I have a ListBox in my xaml file which looks like this:

```
<ListBox Name="collateralPledgedListbox" 
         Style="{StaticResource USB_ListBox}" 
         Margin="0,0,5,39" Width="Auto"  
         ItemsPanel="{StaticResource USB_ListBox_ItemPlacement}"  
         TabNavigation="Local"  
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource USB_ListBoxContainer}"  
         ItemsSource="{Binding Model.CollateralPledgedByMarriedIndividuals, Mode=TwoWay}"  
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource USBcollateralColSumColInfoDataTemplate}"  
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"> 
</ListBox>
```

This ListBox shows a vertical scroll bar when there are number of rows exceed the provided space. 
I am not able to show the currently selected row to the user while tabbing through the controls within the ListBox.

I am using C# as my language. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like all you have to do is set your focus and refresh your view.
Have you tried doing what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10463162/1698987) answer suggests?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MainListBox.SelectedItem = MainListBox.Items[3];
  MainListBox.UpdateLayout(); // Pre-generates item containers 

 var listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem) MainListBox
      .ItemContainerGenerator
      .ContainerFromItem(MainListBox.SelectedItem);

  listBoxItem.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Noctis but this solution would not work as I do not know the index of the selected item.

Comment: could you sketch up your issue? I'm not sure what / why is the problem.