# Focus on first element in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am facing the following issue. When i am removing the first element from a list box which has keyboard focus(by refreshing the item source) the keyboard focus is moving to the parent window. I want to retain the keyboard focus on the fist listbox item. So i came up with the following code

```
<Grid.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FirstRowDeleted}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Using this code i am able to move the focus to the list box itself. How can i move the focus to the first listbox item? MyListBox[0] does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Thanking you
Kaddy

Comment: What about `MyListBox.Items[0]`?

Comment: Value="{Binding ElementName=FavoriteResultListBox.Items[0]}" or Value="{Binding FavoriteResultListBox.Items[0]}" is not working

Comment: My bad, try `Value="{Binding Path=Items[0], ElementName=FavoriteResultListBox}"`

Comment: Even this is not working <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding Path=Items[0], ElementName=MyListBox}" />

Comment: What's the listbox really called? You keep changing your story. Please show enough of your XAML so I can see both the listbox and the Style you have in your question now.

Comment: <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                            Margin="0" 
                            Padding="0"
                            MinWidth="300" Focusable="False"
                            Name="MyListBox" 
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122450/discussion-between-kaddy-and-ed-plunkett).

Comment: I don't have time to pull teeth like this. I have no way of knowing if those two decontextualized snippets are even in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer here: [How do you programmatically set focus to the SelectedItem in a WPF ListBox that already has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444518/how-do-you-programmatically-set-focus-to-the-selecteditem-in-a-wpf-listbox-that)

```
var listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem) MainListBox
    .ItemContainerGenerator
    .ContainerFromItem(MainListBox.SelectedItem);
listBoxItem.Focus();
```

Thanks for @Jeff for the answer.

Answer (score -3):

This code applies the focus function to the first input text when the page loads. try it out

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                $("#input:text:visible:first").focus();


            });
```